# Node.js mysql query rows

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
app.get('/api/db/:tableName', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    dbPool.getConnection(function(objErr, objConn){
        if(objErr){
            sendError(res, 503, 'error', 'connection', objErr); //503 - Service Unavailable
        }else{
            var tableName = req.params.tableName;
            console.log(tableName);
            var tRows, bRows;
            var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');
            var current = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            console.log(typeof today);
            console.log(typeof current);
            if(tableName == 'dashboard'){
                objConn.query("SELECT SUM(taranan) as tTara, SUM(bulunan) as tBul, SUM(resmedilen) as tRes FROM "+tableName, function(Err, Rows, Fields){
                    if(Err){
                        sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
                    }else{
                        tRows = Rows;
                        console.log(bRows);
                    }//else
                });
                objConn.query("SELECT SUM(taranan) as bTara, SUM(bulunan) as bBul, SUM(resmedilen) as bRes FROM "+tableName+" WHERE change_on > '"+today+"'", function(Err, Rows, Fields){
                    if(Err){
                        sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
                    }else{
                        bRows = Rows;
                        console.log(bRows);
                    }//else
                });
                console.log(tRows);
                res.send({
                    results : 'success',
                    err : '',
                    err_type : '',
                    Trows : tRows,
                    Brows : bRows
                });
            }else{
                /* EMPTY ZONE */
            }//else
            objConn.release();
        }//else
    });
});
```

console.logs work perfect. It get the variables in bRows and tRows but last console.log(tRows) is empty. Because when this line running, mysql have not get datas from db yet. How can i fixed this code?

I know its about asynchronous calling.

Comment: You'll have to call the tRows after the callback has been executed.

Comment: You should use `res.send` inside the callback.

Comment: You have two separate async queries running and you need for them both to finish before you send your response. Option 1 is to run your second query inside the callback of the first query, then run your send inside the callback of the second query. Option 2 would be to use promises and have a function that waits until your get responses from both queries before executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said is right, the variables aren't populated because the callback have not been executed (no results returned) yet. A quick fix of your code is:

```
if(tableName == 'dashboard'){
    objConn.query("SELECT SUM(taranan) as tTara, SUM(bulunan) as tBul, SUM(resmedilen) as tRes FROM "+tableName, function(Err, Rows, Fields){
        if(Err){
            sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
        }else{
            tRows = Rows;
            console.log(tRows);

            objConn.query("SELECT SUM(taranan) as bTara, SUM(bulunan) as bBul, SUM(resmedilen) as bRes FROM "+tableName+" WHERE change_on > '"+today+"'", function(Err, Rows, Fields){
                if(Err){
                    sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
                }else{
                    bRows = Rows;
                    console.log(bRows);

                    console.log(tRows);
                    res.send({
                        results : 'success',
                        err : '',
                        err_type : '',
                        Trows : tRows,
                        Brows : bRows
                    });

                }//else
            });

        }//else
    });

}else{
```

This way both `tRows` and `bRows` are already populated when you use them.

### Explanation

What the code I gave does:

- You get the tRows
- You wait for the result of tRows, then you get the bRows
- You wait for the result of bRows, then you send the reply back with bRows and tRows

What was happening in your original code:

- You try to get the tRows
- You try to get get the bRows
- You send the reply (without waiting for the results of bRows and tRows)

### Promises

You might notice that the nested callbacks looks dirty. A better solution is by using promises. Like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

**A few reminders**

Instead of doing a lot of this:

```
if(Err){
  sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
}else{
  tRows = Rows;
  console.log(bRows);
}//else
```

You can try returning early:

```
if (Err) return sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
tRows = Rows;
console.log(bRows);
```

Good luck

Comment: you also might want to fix that first console.log to console.log(tRows)

Comment: @DaveBriand thanks, but this shouldn't really matter as I'm just telling him the idea. But great catch :)

Comment: yes thank you, it works and i understand how to work. But i know my codes is not good, can you share me a documentation to getting better this code?

Comment: @Touregsys if you want to avoid writing more library code by using Promises yourself. Try checking the package called [`knex`](http://knexjs.org). It returns a thenable.

Comment: @majidarif oh ok, ill check it and last question my code seems optimize or not? And thank you very much for your all answers :))

Comment: @Touregsys updated my answer. There are a few things you could change but the code is okay. no need to worry about the optimization.